# Does an ORM for C++ (Object Interface) for Informix exist?

Tags: orm, informix

We use Informix only in our company, there is an old self-made OR mapper, but it's hard to dive into and buggy.

I have just started with Informix and also with C++ after a long break. I have used the IBM C++ Object Interface successfully — for a small project accessing only a few flat tables.

But now I have to use and join many tables, so I'm looking for a way to work with it more effectively.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Hi GrooveHunter, welcome to [dba.se]. Unfortunately, questions about ORMs or OMs or the like really need to goto [so] for more effective answers.